# pyodbc will support connecting to an Azure SQL DB using the AD access token instead of user/password?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

Currently, I use device code credential to get the access to Azure AD.

```
device_code_credential = DeviceCodeCredential(
        azure_client_id,
        tenant_id=azure_tenant_id,
        authority=azure_authority_uri)
```

But I still need to use Azure account username/password to connect to Azure SQL server

```
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
db_connection_string = f'DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};' \
    f'DATABASE={database};UID={user_name};PWD={password};'\
    f'Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;'\
    'Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;'
connector = pyodbc.connect(db_connection_string)
```

Is any way in python under linux/MacOS can allow me to use device_code_credential and access_token to connect to Azure SQL server?

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/228

I only got this link and it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone has a fully working sample?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could reference this tutorial: [AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python: Connect to Azure SQL Database](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database).

It is doable to connect to Azure SQL Database by obtaining a token from Azure Active Directory (AAD), via ADAL Python. We do not currently maintain a full sample for it, but this essay outlines some key ingredients.

1. You follow the instruction of [Connecting using Access Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-2017#connecting-using-access-token) to
   provision your application. There is another similar blog post [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2018/06/06/connect-to-azure-sql-database-by-obtaining-a-token-from-azure-active-directory-aad/).
2. Your SQL admin need to add permissions for the app-registration to
   the specific database that you are trying to access. See details in
   this blog post [Token-based authentication support for Azure SQL DB
   using Azure AD auth](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2016/02/09/token-based-authentication-support-for-azure-sql-db-using-azure-ad-auth/) by Mirek H Sztajno.
3. It was not particularly highlighted in either of the documents
   above, but you need to use `https://database.windows.net/` as the
   resource string. Note that you need to keep the trailing slash,
   otherwise the token issued would not work.
4. Feed the configuration above into ADAL Python's [Client Credentials
   sample](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/1.0.2/sample/client_credentials_sample.py).
5. Once you get the access token, use it [in this way in pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/228#issuecomment-319190980) to
       connect to SQL Database.

This works with AAD access tokens. Example code to expand the token and prepend the length as described on the page linked above, in Python 2.x:

```
token = "eyJ0eXAiOi...";
exptoken = "";
for i in token:
    exptoken += i;
    exptoken += chr(0);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr, attrs_before = { 1256:bytearray(tokenstruct) });
```

3.x is only slightly more involved due to annoying char/bytes split:

```
token = b"eyJ0eXAiOi...";
exptoken = b"";
for i in token:
    exptoken += bytes({i});
    exptoken += bytes(1);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;
conn = pyodbc.connect(connstr, attrs_before = { 1256:tokenstruct });
```

(SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN is 1256; it's specific to msodbcsql driver so pyodbc does not have it defined, and likely will not.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I choose to use clientID and client secret to do the authentication, how could to implement the RBAC? Since any user get the clientID/Secret can access the DB.

Comment: Can you please answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64261711/azure-sql-server-database-ad-token-django. this is a bounty question.

Comment: @Shakthifuture I see the question. But I'm not familiar with Django framework. Is this answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 1):

You can get a token via

```py
from azure.identity import DeviceCodeCredential

# Recommended to allocate a new ClientID in your tenant.
AZURE_CLI_CLIENT_ID = "04b07795-8ddb-461a-bbee-02f9e1bf7b46"
credential = DeviceCodeCredential(client_id=AZURE_CLI_CLIENT_ID)
databaseToken = credential.get_token('https://database.windows.net/.default')
```

Then use databaseToken.token as an AAD Access Token as described in Leon Yue's answer.