# Azure SQL Server connection using MSI - Django

Tags: python, django, azure-sql-database

I have successfully connected the Azure SQL Server using `AccessToken` in the **pyodbc**. Here I didn't use `username` or `password` to connect the database. Instead of that, I used `attrs_before` for pass `token`. Here I am generating the token automatically.

**Token Generation:**

```
identity_endpoint = os.environ["IDENTITY_ENDPOINT"]
identity_header = os.environ["IDENTITY_HEADER"]

def get_bearer_token(resource_uri): #Automattically token will generate
    token_auth_uri = f"{identity_endpoint}?resource={resource_uri}&api-version=2019-08-01"
    head_msi = {'X-IDENTITY-HEADER': identity_header}

    resp = requests.get(token_auth_uri, headers=head_msi)
    access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
    return access_token
```

**Pyodbc Connection:**

```
accessToken = bytes(get_bearer_token("https://database.windows.net/"), 'utf-8');
exptoken = b"";
for i in accessToken:
    exptoken += bytes({i});
    exptoken += bytes(1);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;

conn = pyodbc.connect(
      "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=yoursqlserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=dbName",
      attrs_before={1256: bytearray(tokenstruct)});
```

Now the problem is how to use this in the Django framework to connecting DB? We can't have a `username` or `password`  to connect the database when using azure token.

Please help me out.

Comment: Which OS django prod and dev will are?

Comment: Linux environment

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

in terminal (if not yet installed)

```
pip3 install django-pyodbc-azure
pip3 install django-azure-sql-backend
```

In Azure portal you have to check what is tenant_id and client_id. Since you are connecting from pyodbc, I assume you have those. Empty port means default

in settings.py:

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'your_database',
        'HOST': 'yourserver.database.example.net',
        'PORT': '',
        'AAD-AUTH': {
            'tenant_id': 'tenant_id',
            'client_id': 'client_id',
            'secret': "SECRET_KEY",
        },
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

set this to False if you want to turn off pyodbc's connection pooling

```
DATABASE_CONNECTION_POOLING = False
```

If ODBC Driver 17 failed, try:

```
'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server'
```

If you do not have SECRET_KEY, you can get it during app registration. (Yes to get the key, you have to make it an app)

1. Log in to the Azure portal.
2. On the top search bar, type “Azure Active Directory” and click the Active directory or Click on More Services on the left-hand side, and choose the Azure Active Directory
3. Click on App registrations and Click “New application registration”
4. Provide a name and URL for the application.
5. From the App registrations in Azure Active Directory, select your application.
6. Copy the Application ID
7. Click Settings on the same window.
8. To generate an authentication key, Click "Keys".
9. Update a description of the key, and a duration and value which is your password, select Save.

Let us know how it went

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have updated my code, can you please check. Here even I am getting the token automatically. This library using secret key, actually my code using token.

Comment: Try deleting 'secret': "SECRET KEY" line. Let's test

Comment: on the bottom I included info how to create SECRET_KEY

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223721/discussion-between-kamil-and-shakthifuture).

Answer (score 0):

Use this package to handle this feature.

```
pip install azure-msi-mssql-django
```

then configure **settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',
        'IS_AZURE_BASED_TOKEN': True
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

If you are using a **local SQL server**, use this configuration.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'mydb',
        'USER': 'user@myserver',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'myserver.database.windows.net',
        'PORT': '',
        'IS_AZURE_BASED_TOKEN': False

        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        },
    },
}
```

More details: https://pypi.org/project/azure-msi-mssql-django/